# Central limit theorem using it with formulas

Tags: statistics, trigonometry

1.The average amount of money spent at lunch in the wissakion cafeteria is 3.00  dollars with a standard deviation of 75 cents. Assume the distribution of money spent is normal.
a. What is the probability that a student spends more than 3.50$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculator 2nd VARS normalcdf(3.5,10^99,3.00,75)=.50 or 50%

Answer (score 1):

This is the probability that a normal random variable is more than $\dfrac{0.50}{0.75}$ "standard deviation units" above the mean. That's the probability that a standard normal $Z$ is greater than $\dfrac{0.50}{0.75}$. You can now find the information from a table of the standard normal.

Comment: If I can add one more piece of information. What is the probability that the average amount spent by an SRS of 10 student will be greater than 4?

Comment: The average of $10$ has mean 3.00, and standard deviation $\frac{0.75}{\sqrt{10}}$. Now use same basic method, different "standard deviation unit."  The probability will turn out to be very very small.